# Nltk lesk issue

Tags: nltk, wordnet

I am running a simple sentence disambiguation test. But the synset returned by nltk Lesk for the word **'cat'** in the sentence "The cat likes milk" is 'kat.n.01', synsetid=3608870. 
(n) kat, khat, qat, quat, cat, Arabian tea, African tea (the leaves of the shrub Catha edulis which are chewed like tobacco or used to make tea; has the effect of a euphoric stimulant) "in Yemen kat is used daily by 85% of adults"
This is a simple phrase and yet the disambiguation task fails.

And this is happening for many words in a set containing more than one sentence, for example in my test sentences, I would expect 'dog' to be disambiguated as 'domestic dog' but Lesk gives me  'pawl' (a hinged catch that fits into a notch of a ratchet to move a wheel forward or prevent it from moving backward) 
Is it related to the size of the training set which is in my test only few sentences?

Here is my test code:

`def test_lesk():
    words = get_sample_words()
    print(words)
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
    tags = tagger.tag(words)
    print (tags[:5])
    for word, tag in tags:
      pos = get_wordnet_pos(tag)
      if pos is None:
          continue
      print("word=%s,tag=%s,pos=%s" %(word, tag, pos))
      synset = lesk(words, word, pos)
      if synset is None:
          print('No synsetid for word=%s' %word)
      else:
          print('word=%s, synsetname=%s, synsetid=%d' %(word,synset.name(), synset.offset()))`

Comment: Probably your guess is correct: if you train a tagger on a few sentences only, then it's quite unlikely that you will get decent tagging quality.

Comment: The tagger gives me the right tag for 'cat', the issue is lesk which solves the disambiguation by giving me the synset related to 'kat'. Giving to lesk the whole corpus is also time consuming, hence the reason to break it down into smaller contexts.

Comment: No model is perfect and lesk is one of the most basic and ancient in WSD ;P